# error when send special character from c# to webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, post

im using method POST to send string to REST service.

```
 //--------------------------Method Post--------------------------
    public static string methodPost(string header,string url,string body)
    {

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        if(header!=null) request.Headers.Add(header);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        var response = request.GetResponse();

        Stream stream2 = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
        String ok = reader2.ReadToEnd();
        return ok;
    }
```

if string body ="test send string" : success, but string body ="test send ' string" : not success. 
how to fix it? thank!

Comment: If your Rest service ADO Layet yet,this replacement try... http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/113/Preventing-SQL-Injection-in-ASP.NET

Comment: Or try  my simple ext:`public static class Ext
    {
        
        public static string AsAntiInjection(this string str)
        {
            return str.Replace("'", "''");
        }

    }`

Answer (score 0):

`"test send ' string"` is legal json, but you might try `"test send \' string"`.  If that doesn't work, you'll need to ask the people who manage the web service.